# How to read a token from Input file?

Tags: perl

I have a input , it looks like this

Input File

```
ID                   Score1  Score2
ABC                     1      2
DEF                     30     50
```

I want to get the ID and two scores in each lines , and I succeed , But I want to ask does there exist any function can get a word ? that means I call this function three times then I can get the ID and two scores ....

```
while( eof(Input) !=1)
{
    $C = getc(Input);
    if($C eq "\n")
    {
        $Signal = 0;
        print Output @Elements;
        print Output "\n";
        @Elements = ();
    }
    elsif($C ne " ")
    {
        if($Signal == 1)
        {
            push(@Elements,"-");
            $Signal = 0;
        }
        push(@Elements,$C);
    }
    else
    {
        $Signal = 1;
    }
}
```

I found that

```
$Line = readline(*Input);
@Line_elements = split(" ",$Line);
```

can work .....

thanks

Comment: Please try to figure out a better title for your question. Right now, the title really does not describe the problem, and I am not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to write C in Perl?

Comment: No! It can't be true! I see C-coding on Perl! My eyes! :\

Comment: I write C before , so it is a little bit weird ....I will try to describe better , my English is bad :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly should be output (better is to provide exact sample input and exact sample output but you can use something like this if you want only lines which starts witch string id and then two numeric scores:

```
while ( $line = <STDIN> ) {
  my ($id, $score1, $score2) = ( $line =~ /^([A-Z]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)$/ );
  print $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
my ($id, $score1, $score2) = split / +/, $Line;
```

/ +/ is a regular expression; it takes care about one or more blank spaces

Comment: Or even simpler `split ' ', $Line`